# How can I Flash my Bricked Huawei P40Lite with stock firmware

Tags: huawei, device-firmware

My Huawei P40 Lite "accidentally" switched off while updating in recovery mode and is now stuck on the boot logo and turns off. I tried the eRecovery mode to download the stock firmware but it says "Get package info failed". I've tried flashing it using OTG and USB drive with dload folder and it didn't work. I've also tried using fastboot but USB debugging is off so I cannot use any flashing tool. Please Help!